# Knowledge Articles in Napili template

Tags: community, napili

How to add knowledge article in napili template. I can see only home page could be visible in napili template. Is there any way by which we can add or activate knowledge article for napili template.

Comment: Is knowledge enabled and set up? Data categories etc? This is for another template but should be of help.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxDOeA7iay8

Comment: @Richard N that video is no more applicable ,you cannot edit main and other assets in Napili now .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to set up data categories first

Provide access to your data categories

You will then navigate to the Navigational Topics and associate the Topics with articles

[image]

Also make sure your article types are visible to guest as well as community users

Comment: Thank you very much Mohith. Your answer lead to a chain of configurations that I needed to make. Once done that now I am able to view KA in community.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Salesforce Trailhead that shows the steps necessary in detail. The Trail is called "[Build a Community with Knowledge and Chat](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/build-a-community-with-knowledge-and-chat)" and the specific module is called "[Add Knowledge to the Community Using Topics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/build-a-community-with-knowledge-and-chat/steps/add-knowledge-to-the-community-using-topics)".

Comment: please review the [answer] section, although this may answer the question, links may become broken, thus it is important to include the relevant section to better address the op's needs.